# Can I pass 'wandb' object to another class in python?

Tags: python, logging, wandb

I have written a modular code and I wanted to pass a wandb object to a class which has been written in another .py file. I instantiated a wandb object using:

```
import wandb 
exp_name = "expriment name"
run = wandb.init(config = wandb.config, project= exp_name, entity="username")
```

at the top of the main.py file. Now whenever I need to log anything I use `run.log({'Accuracy/train': 100.0 * n_class_corrected / total_class_samples}, step=iteration)`
and it works when I call it within the main.py or if I pass it to a function. But I am still wondering when I pass it to a class defined in another .py file it is not going to log anything.
Overall my question is how should I pass a wandb object to another class which is in another .py file. Is there any consideration that I should pay attention to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it around just as you would pass any object. You can also just call `import wandb` in the other file, and rather than passing around the object you can call `wandb.log` in that file. W&B will be smart enough to log it to the same run.

```
file_1: 
from file_2 import something_else
import wandb
wandb.init(...)
wandb.log(...)
something_else()

file_2:
import wandb

def something_else():
    wandb.log({'something_else': 123})
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott, for your answer. I did that but it seems it loses the context, so when the "log" is run nothing will be logged indeed. This is the case when I pass the wandb as an object to a class that has been defined in another .py file. Please let me know if you need any detail.

Comment: I just tested this locally and was able to log from two files without issue.

That worked fine. I edited the original answer. Let me know if that's unclear and I can try help.